# Is a finite dimensional vector also a covector?

Tags: vector-spaces, terminology, definition

I am reading something where it seems they have defined a covector/linear functional as a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ where $F$ is a vector

For example, $F(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}x$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Pick $x = [1, 0]^T$, then $F(x) = 1$. The action of the covector is the standard inner product.

I was super confused because the notation $F(x)$ reminded me of a linear map.

Excuse my ignroance as I have never seen a covector defined this way. Is this a legit covector?

Comment: A vector space over a field is defined as a set with two operations on it (scalar multiplication and vector addition). Its dual space is defined as the set of all linear maps from said vector space to said field (fields are one-dimensional vector spaces over themselves). A covector is defined as an element of this dual space. So, in case of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if you choose to display its elements as column vectors, then a covector (a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$) can be displayed as a row vector, which act on column vectors via standard matrix multiplication.